# MS Excel crashes when running VBA to Communicate through DDE/OPC to an RSLogix PLC

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am currently running MS Excel 2010 on my Windows laptop. I am attempting to communicate via DDE/OPC through RSLinx Classic v2.57 with an RSLogix 5000 PLC. Every time the VBA code runs to do this, my Excel becomes unresponsive. I know there is not a problem with the code itself because it runs fine on all of my coworkers' computers. Also, if i install excel in a VM session, it runs perfect there as well. For some reason it just will not work on my host computer. I've been able to run this same macro on my host in the past but for the past year or so I have not. I feel like there is some setting that was changed somehow or a service that isn't running that should be. I've even had IT uninstall and reinstall Excel and that did not fix the problem. Has anyone ever run into this issue before? Let me know if you need any further information. Any feedback is appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to my own problem (at least for now). If I opened the Task Manager and went to Performance>Resource Manager, right clicked on excel then "Analyze Wait Chains", I saw that it was waiting for some .exe file that turned out to be associated with my LogiTech mouse. I Ended that Process and it fixed my problem.

I coworker just told me about the wait chains, i had never heard of them before so I never knew to check that.

Answer (score 0):

There are several potential causes.  If it works on your coworker's computers, it is likely an issue with something causing excel top fail to read using RSLinx.  For each tag, it will hang until it times out, and then move onto the next tag, which can cause excel to become unresponsive.

Potential causes can include:

- If you don't have a Linx license installed, Linx will run as Lite which does not support DDE.
- Have you verified that you have the topic configured within Linx?
- Excel sometimes fails to start RSLinx if it is not running.  Try running Linx manually.
- Windows firewall can block linx from talking to the PLC

To troubleshoot, try reading the target tags manually using the OPC Test Client that comes with RSLinx (shortcut in start menu).  This allows you to verify linx can talk to the PLC when browsing PLC tags directly.  You can also browse the topic to verify it is set up correctly, which is what excel uses through DDE.  Then use the DDE client diagnostics within the RSLinx menu "DDE/OPC" to check for errors when running excel to read tags.  It can help you diagnose typos in tags and topic names.